# Cannot use STL function for typedefed template

Tags: c++

I have created a `typedef` for `map` but cannot use the `find` method. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef std::map<std::string, int> customType;
    customType mod;

    mod["something"] = 2;

    if (mod.find("something"))
    {
        std::cout << "found";
    }
}
```

for the above code I am getting an error as follows:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:22:17: error: could not convert ‘mod.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::find, int, std::less >, std::allocator, int> > >(std::basic_string(((const char*)"something"), std::allocator()))’ from ‘std::map, int>::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator, int> >}’ to ‘bool’
     if (mod.find("something"))
         ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I know I can directly use `std::map` without `typedef` but this code is just an example for something I want to do in a project. Please help me to find a way to use the `find` method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with templates and typedefs. Rather, you are using the `find` method incorrectly. The behavior of [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) is described as follows:

> [Returns an] Iterator to an element with key equivalent to key. If no such element is found, past-the-end (see `end()`) iterator is returned.

To check if key exists (i.e. the iterator is valid), you can check to make sure the iterator is not equal to the past-the-end iterator:

```
if (mod.find("something") != mod.end())
```

In C++20 onwards, you can directly use the [`contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/contains) method for membership testing:

```
if (mod.contains("something"))
```